# Looking for a children's or young adult novel about three kids travelling to a fantasy land

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, childrens-novel

I've been trying to remember the title of a children's or young adult book I read as a child about thirty years ago. (So it may be from '70s or '80s). I don't remember many of the details.

There were three main protagonists; I want to say that all three were boys (maybe one was a girl), one of them may have been from India and the other two from the US or UK.  The three end up in a fantasy land with an evil king or prince.

There's a **giant "inchworm" that the three characters can ride on saddles, which means that the middle rider goes up and down as the worm moves**.  As the worm is running from guards at one point, the middle rider gets jammed up into a crack in the ceiling of a tunnel and gets separated from the other two.

I also vaguely remember a scene where **a character eats some glowing mushrooms and ends up glowing himself**, being mistaken for a ghost.

Odd memories, but I do remember enjoying the book as a child and would like to read it to my own son.  I've made multiple searches online trying to word the search in every way I can think of without success.